# Scraping dictionary using curl

Tags: php, shell, dictionary, curl, web-scraping

for academic reasons I need to scrape a North Korean dictionary (having already informed myself about the copyright-related issues), which 'actually' should be quite simple: The website is returned by a PHP script, which just uses ascending numbers in the URLs for each dictionary entry is:

uriminzokkiri.com/uri_foreign/dic/index.php?page=1

and the last entry is located at:

uriminzokkiri.com/uri_foreign/dic/index.php?page=313372

So basically I'd assume that the easiest way to do this is writing a simple shell script where the number of entry gets incremented using a loop construction, plus checking whether a site got downloaded successfully, since the connection is not good, so that it repeats trying to download the site until it was successful (also trivial).

But then I tried to download a site containing an entry to test this, which failed. The site makes use of session cookies, so I first saved the according cookie in a file using the "-c" parameter and then invoked curl with the "-v" (verbose) and "-b" (get cookie(s) from file) parameter, which produced the following output:

[curl output](http://pastebin.com/kjaWYJzp)

These are the request and response headers as being shown by Firebug:
[Request/Response headers](http://pasteboard.co/Nlt9Zvpxs.jpg)

I also tried to pass all these request headers using the "-H" parameter, however this didn't work neither.

Someone started coding a Python-based scraper for scraping this dictionary, but if this could be realized using a simple bash script, then this looks a bit like an overkill to me.

Does anyone know why the approach I tried so far doesn't work and how this could be achieved?

Many thanks in advance and kind regards

Comment: I used the command you shared in pastebin (which btw should have been shared in the question as well) and it worked just fine in getting the page. Now all you need to do is scrape the HTML using some sort of HTML parser or a regex to find the entry you need (Python doesn't sound like an overkill anymore does it?)

Comment: Sorry, for some odd reason I shortened the URL by mistake: "&ID=1" (for the first entry) must be added, as one can see in the Firebug headers, so it's http://uriminzokkiri.com/uri_foreign/dic/index.php?page=1&ID=1 If I enter this address in a browser, a site containing the entry is returned, but for scraping it I need to get the content of [div#dic_desc_center](http://pasteboard.co/NmhG2WTbg.jpg) Firebug says: "get" or "set" belonging to property with [LenientThis] ignored, because "this" object is incorrect. How could I get "dic_desc_center" / where does it point to? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

you could put some more Http-Headers like:

- Origin: witch is domain of original site you scrap.
- User-Agent: witch is your client configuration witch you can get from internet.

---

otherwise you can get bash curl script from your browser code inspection then convert it to php code. all automated and exist online.

Comment: Thanks for your hints. I already tried passing every HTTP header which was passed by Firefox, with no success (origin, user-agent, caching, cookie, etc.). PHP and DOM/DIV elements are certainly not part of my knowledge (I'm specialized in Linux administration and C/C++ programming) - The site must call the content of this DIV object from somewhere, so is there no way to trace this?